# cupola based hydrocarbons

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula

My favorite groups of shapes are [cupolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupola_(geometry)). Are there hydrocarbons in the shape of these similar to how cubane is to a cube? If so how stable are they, and could you please give some general information about each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They would be highly unstable due to the inverted tetrahedral geometry of the carbons in the top face. Generally, a polyhedron can form the basis of a stable hydrocarbon if it has at most 3 edges for each corner. A big caveat is that the hydrocarbon will distort the shape if the angle strain is too great. I found that out in my computational research on prismanes.

Comment: So one does exist, the diagonal cupola exists.

Comment: Yes, that would be [prismane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prismane)

Answer (score 2):

If one forgets about the correct mathematical notation for a moment:

- a cupola is like a bowl
- a bowl is a fragment of a spherical object

Molecules of this shape are found in the field of fullerenes (*bucky balls*).

One of the most simple bowl-shaped molecules is *sumanene*. If you like to play a bit with the structure, please fetch [sumanene.cml](http://pastebin.com/tYTjD2JL) from pastebin and open it in [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/).

[image: structure of sumanene]

The shape is more obvious in the following animation.

[image: animation of sumanene]

The structure of two extended bowl-shaped molecules has been published in 
*J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **2011**, *133*, 16319–16321 (
[DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja2067725)), and although they are not true cupolas, you might find them interesting anyway.

I've uploaded the structures [bowl-01.cml](http://pastebin.com/MZgdHkY6) and [bowl-02.cml](http://pastebin.com/u1WD455w) as CML files.